# php multi array grouping and maximum value each group and sum per array

Tags: php, arrays, sum, max, grouping

php multi array grouping `Array [0]` and each group maximum `Array [3]` value.
The following array represent  `Array [0]` - id, `Array [1]` - price, `Array [2]` - product name, `Array [3]` - shipping price, `Array [4]` - shipping method
Each array need to be group by id then sum per group price and use maximum shipping cost.
The output i have listed below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2200.00
            [2] => Portable Hard Drive
            [3] => 120.00
            [4] => Taxi
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 8500.00
            [2] => HP Laptop
            [3] => 80.00
            [4] => Taxi
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 700.00
            [2] => Luxury Watch
            [3] => 200.00
            [4] => TAXI FAST
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1500.00
            [2] => VGA DISTRIBUTE
            [3] => 300.00
            [4] => EMS
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 5000.00
            [2] => 3D Camera
            [3] => 150.00
            [4] => DHL
        )
)
```

List of output show like this or you can put in array

```
1-5000.00-3D Camera-150.00-DHL
1-700.00-Luxury Watch-200.00-TAXI FAST
Total price = 5700.00
Max of ship = 200.00
Grand total = 5900.00
2-2200.00-Portable Hard Drive-120.00-taxi
2-8500.00-HP Laptop-80.00-Taxi
2-1500.00-VGA DISTRIBUTE-300.00-EMS
Total price = 12200.00
Max of ship = 300.00
Grand total = 12500.00
This order Total price 17900.00
This order Total max ship 500.00
This order Grand Total 18400.00
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This site is not a code writing service; you are expected to at least make an _attempt_ to try and solve the problem yourself - and if you can not get it to work on your own, then at least _show us_ what you tried.

Comment: This question contains no coding attempt and is asking for too many different techniques to be executed in concert.  This question Needs More Focus.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need much more than a `foreach` to achieve this. `array_column` `array_sum` and `max` can help.

Split the task into some smaller ones:

- from your initial list build the result data holder
- group items into groups by their id
- sort groups by id
- iterate groups and calculate for each group the total price, max shipping and grand total
- also update total price and total max ship while processing each group
- calculate the grand total
- display the data as you want as your structure already holds all the needed data

```
<?php

$input = [
    0 => [
            0 => 2,
            1 => 2200.00,
            2 => 'Portable Hard Drive',
            3 => 120.00,
            4 => 'Taxi'
        ],
    1 => [
            0 => 2,
            1 => 8500.00,
            2 => 'HP Laptop',
            3 => 80.00,
            4 => 'Taxi',
        ],
    2 => [
            0 => 1,
            1 => 700.00,
            2 => 'Luxury Watch',
            3 => 200.00,
            4 => 'TAXI FAST',
        ],
    3 => [
            0 => 2,
            1 => 1500.00,
            2 => 'VGA DISTRIBUTE',
            3 => 300.00,
            4 => 'EMS',
        ],
    4 => [
            0 => 1,
            1 => 5000.00,
            2 => '3D Camera',
            3 => 150.00,
            4 => 'DHL',
        ]
];

const ID = 0;
const PRICE = 1;
const PRODUCT_NAME = 2;
const SHIPPING_PRICE = 3;
const SHIPPING_METHOD = 4;

// build initial result, populate groups (items groupped by id)
$result = [
  'groups' => [],
  'totalPrice' => 0,
  'shippingPriceMax' => 0,
];
foreach($input as $item) {
  $result['groups'][$item[ID]]['products'][] = $item;
}

// sord ids descending
ksort($result['groups'], SORT_NUMERIC);

var_dump($result);

// for every group calculate total price, max shipping and grand total
foreach($result['groups'] as $id => $group) {
  $result['groups'][$id]['totalPrice'] = array_sum(array_column($group['products'], PRICE));
  $result['groups'][$id]['shippingPriceMax'] = max(array_column($group['products'], SHIPPING_PRICE));
  $result['groups'][$id]['grandTotal'] = $result['groups'][$id]['totalPrice'] + $result['groups'][$id]['shippingPriceMax'];

  // update also total values for all groups
  $result['totalPrice'] += $result['groups'][$id]['totalPrice'];
  $result['shippingPriceMax'] += $result['groups'][$id]['shippingPriceMax'];
}
$result['grandTotal'] = $result['totalPrice'] + $result['shippingPriceMax'];

var_dump($result);

// build the output
$output = '';
foreach($result['groups'] as $id => $group) {
  foreach($group['products'] as $product) {
    $output .= $product[ID].'-'.number_format($product[PRICE],2,'.','').'-'.$product[PRODUCT_NAME].'-'.number_format($product[SHIPPING_PRICE],2,'.','').'-'.$product[SHIPPING_METHOD].PHP_EOL;
  }
  
  $output .= 'Total price = '.number_format($group['totalPrice'],2,'.','').PHP_EOL;
  $output .= 'Max of ship = '.number_format($group['shippingPriceMax'],2,'.','').PHP_EOL;
  $output .= 'Grand total = '.number_format($group['grandTotal'],2,'.','').PHP_EOL;
}
$output .= 'This order Total price '.number_format($result['totalPrice'],2,'.','').PHP_EOL;
$output .= 'This order Total max ship '.number_format($result['shippingPriceMax'],2,'.','').PHP_EOL;
$output .= 'This order Grand Total '.number_format($result['grandTotal'],2,'.','');

var_dump($output);
```

Initial $result after creating groups by id and sorting them by id:

```
array(3) {
  ["groups"]=>
  array(2) {
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["products"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(5) {
          [0]=>
          int(1)
          [1]=>
          float(700)
          [2]=>
          string(12) "Luxury Watch"
          [3]=>
          float(200)
          [4]=>
          string(9) "TAXI FAST"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(5) {
          [0]=>
          int(1)
          [1]=>
          float(5000)
          [2]=>
          string(9) "3D Camera"
          [3]=>
          float(150)
          [4]=>
          string(3) "DHL"
        }
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      ["products"]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        array(5) {
          [0]=>
          int(2)
          [1]=>
          float(2200)
          [2]=>
          string(19) "Portable Hard Drive"
          [3]=>
          float(120)
          [4]=>
          string(4) "Taxi"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(5) {
          [0]=>
          int(2)
          [1]=>
          float(8500)
          [2]=>
          string(9) "HP Laptop"
          [3]=>
          float(80)
          [4]=>
          string(4) "Taxi"
        }
        [2]=>
        array(5) {
          [0]=>
          int(2)
          [1]=>
          float(1500)
          [2]=>
          string(14) "VGA DISTRIBUTE"
          [3]=>
          float(300)
          [4]=>
          string(3) "EMS"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["totalPrice"]=>
  int(0)
  ["shippingPriceMax"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

$result after calculating all needed data (this contains everything we need to display it):

```
array(4) {
  ["groups"]=>
  array(2) {
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      ["products"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(5) {
          [0]=>
          int(1)
          [1]=>
          float(700)
          [2]=>
          string(12) "Luxury Watch"
          [3]=>
          float(200)
          [4]=>
          string(9) "TAXI FAST"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(5) {
          [0]=>
          int(1)
          [1]=>
          float(5000)
          [2]=>
          string(9) "3D Camera"
          [3]=>
          float(150)
          [4]=>
          string(3) "DHL"
        }
      }
      ["totalPrice"]=>
      float(5700)
      ["shippingPriceMax"]=>
      float(200)
      ["grandTotal"]=>
      float(5900)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(4) {
      ["products"]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        array(5) {
          [0]=>
          int(2)
          [1]=>
          float(2200)
          [2]=>
          string(19) "Portable Hard Drive"
          [3]=>
          float(120)
          [4]=>
          string(4) "Taxi"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(5) {
          [0]=>
          int(2)
          [1]=>
          float(8500)
          [2]=>
          string(9) "HP Laptop"
          [3]=>
          float(80)
          [4]=>
          string(4) "Taxi"
        }
        [2]=>
        array(5) {
          [0]=>
          int(2)
          [1]=>
          float(1500)
          [2]=>
          string(14) "VGA DISTRIBUTE"
          [3]=>
          float(300)
          [4]=>
          string(3) "EMS"
        }
      }
      ["totalPrice"]=>
      float(12200)
      ["shippingPriceMax"]=>
      float(300)
      ["grandTotal"]=>
      float(12500)
    }
  }
  ["totalPrice"]=>
  float(17900)
  ["shippingPriceMax"]=>
  float(500)
  ["grandTotal"]=>
  float(18400)
}
```

Output:

```
string(407) "1-700.00-Luxury Watch-200.00-TAXI FAST
1-5000.00-3D Camera-150.00-DHL
Total price = 5700.00
Max of ship = 200.00
Grand total = 5900.00
2-2200.00-Portable Hard Drive-120.00-Taxi
2-8500.00-HP Laptop-80.00-Taxi
2-1500.00-VGA DISTRIBUTE-300.00-EMS
Total price = 12200.00
Max of ship = 300.00
Grand total = 12500.00
This order Total price 17900.00
This order Total max ship 500.00
This order Grand Total 18400.00"
```

The only difference between this and your output is that in group id: 1 I have `Luxury Watch` first and `3D Camera` second and this is the order in your input array. For group id: 2 the order is the same.

Comment: i tried this working but no need assign `const` because many type of data there. if you can short code run this `array` input https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b1HE

Comment: If you dont want to use consts then just remove them and replace them with their values. So remove `const ID = 0;` and replace `ID` occurrences with `0` and the same for the rest of them. You also dont need consts for every key, you can have only those indexes you use. It increases readability. Check this line `array_sum(array_column($group['products'], PRICE));` vs this `array_sum(array_column($group['products'], 1));`. Which one is easier to understand? If the code works for you it should be easy to modify it to your needs?